# Equation Style Text+Math Left Aligned

Tags: align, amsmath

I am aware that if you type:

```
       Hello \begin{equation} a+b=hi\end{equation}
```

the equation would jump to another line. If we put

```
 \begin{equation} \text{Hello} a+b=hi\end{equation}
```

the Hello is not left aligned, meaning it is centered with the equation.
How can we put 0 indent to text and include it in the equation? I want 
Text+math in ONE line but Text is flushleft and still math is centered.

I have seen some previous complicated answers. Shouldnt Latex people create this simple command? Let say \lefttag{}? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\begin{flalign} &\text{Hello} &a+b&=hi &&\end{flalign}
```

should do it.

You also can try this:

```
\begin{gather}
\intertext{Hello\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip + \abovedisplayskip\relax}}
a + b = hi
\end{gather}
```